# System proxy configuration does not work

Tags: firefox, proxy

For some reaon I can't connect the internet via the school proxy. This only applies to apt-get, Firefox with automatic proxy detection works just fine. I already tried setting up the proxy in /etc/apt.conf.d/01-proxy and as export in my bash.rc, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Why don’t you set the proxy in Firefox preferences?

Comment: As I said, it works in Firefox, but apt-get for example does not work, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/apt/apt.conf, or create it if it doesn't exist. Add the following code:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
```

To do this automatically on network startup, create a file called "zproxy" (or something along those lines) containing the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "`sudo iwlist eth1 scanning | grep mySSID`" ]
then
    echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
    echo 'Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
    echo 'Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyserver:port/";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
else
    echo '' > /etc/apt/apt.conf
fi
```

Replace mySSID with the SSID of your school's network, and "username:password@proxyserver:port" with the correct proxy settings. Put the file in /etc/network/if-up.d/ and mark it executable using

> ~$: sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/zproxy

The bash script will run every time you connect to the network, and either append your proxy settings to /etc/apt/apt.conf or clear the file entirely.